# How to insert an android activity into the manifest given in a tutorial?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am very new to android development with eclipse, and I encounter dozen of errors and problems. Here is the next one:

I am following an android tutorial given [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/setting-up.html#ApiLevel7) in order to set up the action bar. In this tutorial is says to insert an activity as follows:

```
<activity android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" ... >
```

Can I just put this line into the xml manifest file?

```
<activity android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

Or do I need to replace the '...' by something more useful?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you really want your app to work under API levels under 3.0 then you have to add it like this.

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
```

Inside your already defined activity in your manifest (the one that has the intent filter and other declarations).

otherwise you dont have to add that at all.

This is one example.

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and this is another

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme=@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"" >
    <activity android:name=".DetailActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    </activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please read the docs: [activity-element](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

The activity's name is required, so you would need to have:

```
<activity android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" android:name="MyActivity">
```

Other than that, you are not *required* to add any other attributes.

Although be sure to place the activity element within the proper place in your xml. It should be contained in your application block:

```
 <application android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">

        <activity android:name="MyActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Comment: I am following a tutorial. After that I read the docs, not before!

Answer (score -1):

The second way you posted is just fine, be sure to close the activity tag so it looks like `<activity android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"></activity>`

Also, if you're using eclipse, it is easier to go into the AndroidManifest and under the `Application` tab scroll to the bottom where there's `Application Nodes` and then add your view from there. Eclipse will auto generate the correct code in the xml file.